# how to display the day on which a user born in mysql?

Tags: mysql, string, date

I want to display the day on which a user born. I have **date-of-birth column in my table in date Format**. So please let me know the solution for the problem. I tried myself, then I tried to get it over internet, but got several results for other database like oracle and sqlserver, so please let me know how to get it .

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Do you want day as monday, tuesday etc. Like say for 1st Dec 2012 day is Saturday. Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[edit]

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2012-12-27');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

Comment: See my edit. But if you need to internationalise your output, you'd better use `DAYOFWEEK` and do the mapping in your application layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with %w or %W:

```
DATE_FORMAT('2012-12-27', '%w');
```

- %W = Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
- %w = Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)

Answer (score 1):

Use [EXTRACT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function

```
select  
     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BirthDate), 
     EXTRACT(MONTH FROM BirthDate), 
     EXTRACT(DAY FROM BirthDate) 
from t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2012-12-27');
```

**Output**

```
Thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

if you name of day then use :-

```
 SELECT DAYNAME('2007-02-03');
```

or if want day of week then use

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK('2012-12-27);
```

for more detail visit:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname